# Dynamically sized UITextview inside a prototype cell, ios8 and ios7

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

Note I am using AutoLayout for this case.

From what I understand to get A customTableViewCell to dynamically size, I have to use this after viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

This allowed the height to resize dynamically to fit my two fields
Title and my UITextView, by their constraint size.

Though I want my UITextView to dynamically expand the cell.

I have tried this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    CGRect frame = cell.descriptionTextView.frame;
    CGSize content = cell.descriptionTextView.contentSize;

    CGSize contentSize = [cell.descriptionTextView sizeThatFits:cell.descriptionTextView.frame.size];
    NSLog(@"FrameSize:%f Content:%f",frame.size.height, contentSize.height);
    cell.descriptionTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = contentSize.height;

    [cell.descriptionTextView sizeToFit];

}
```

UITextView does not appear resize according to the content size to fit 
Lorem ipsem fit inside the UITextView.

I have a feeling that the content size height is off.

Image attached below.

http://imgur.com/aZnm0sZ

What I want to do is have the UITextView dynamically resize and the cell to dynamically resize, when I am typing in it.

This seems like the solution
http://www.howlin-interactive.com/2013/01/creating-a-self-sizing-uitextview-within-a-uitableviewcell-in-ios-6/

I am wondering if there was a recent solution.

Thanks I have looked at bunch of these explanations on SO and nothing thus far as come to help out, I feel that I have to do this 100% programmatically